# How to determine IBM USB 6 pin header pinout?

Tags: usb, pinout, motherboard

I have two IBM Power 7 machines - Power720 and Power740 (8202-E4B and 8205-E6B) and both have an internal USB 6 pin header (labelled J3_TAPEUSB_SIGNAL). These are for connection to a single device (either an LTO drive, an RDX drive, etc.).

[image: IBM 6 pin USB header]

The IBM cable is either unobtainable or the price is insane, so I decided to just make one myself.

I am going to mount an RDX drive (dock). I already got the parts (the RDX, a USB Type B cable and a Dupont style 2x3 connector). Now the problem is, how do I determine the header pinout (using a multimeter, etc.) without frying the motherboard, port or any device attached to it?

I searched all over the place for IBM-related pinout information to no avail. So this is basically a hands-on job, hopefully without toasting anything.

Any help or pointers appreciated.

EDIT:

These are resistance and voltage readings I took as per @KH's recommendations:

[image: readings]

As for other components/devices nearby, this is it (bottom right SAS backplane cable removed for clarity):

[image: power720]

I tested impedance on the front and back USB Type A ports (receptacles) and got 1.2 Ohms on pin 4 (which can maybe match pin 3 top right on the header). All others infinity.

[image]

All readings done against the chassis.

Comment: You can start by attempting to find the ground pin.  Power down the mobo obviously, and meter voltage (to confirm 0) and resistance to ground on all 6 pins.  Hopefully one should have much lower impedance.  For +5V, you can power the motherboard and meter voltage on all 6 pins, and the remaining 4 pins should be 2 data sets.  Inspect thoroughly to figure out which of those 4 are paired with each other if you can, and hopefully someone around here has a method of determining data wire polarity.  Devices may not detect if they're reversed, I'm just not sure of potential for damage.

Comment: Once you know which are power and ground you may be able to just connect the data wires both ways to see which one works.  [One of the answers to this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/73295/in-a-usb-cable-is-it-ok-to-swap-the-d-and-d-wires) does not imply that devices will be damaged, but that is hardly a guarantee.  I assume your measurement tools are limited to a multimeter?

Comment: do you know the part number for the cable?

Comment: https://www.ebay.ca/itm/IBM-Front-Usb-Power-And-Data-Cable-for-3650M4-XSERIES-SERVER-81Y6770/283247606039?hash=item41f2df7917:g:om8AAOSwsupb4fbB:rk:1:pf:0

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 That photo shows a cable assembly that definitely doesn't fit in this connector (just count the wires...)

Comment: OK.   TY Marcus for keeping me honest. I wonder how where he found these 2 expensive machines.

Comment: @KH, Yes, I am just limited to a multimeter. I'll try the method you mention.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I got these machines locally for US$250 and US$325, both 8 core 32 threads, 32GB and 64GB RAM, etc. Running SuSE and Fedora perfectly. I jumped on them on the spot. Blazing fast database performance.

Comment: @jsotola The IBM part number is 46K7435 but I've seen the same cable with different connectors...

Comment: cool.. 800MHz RAM? 3GHz CPU?  http://www.112it.com/p/46K7435

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 One has 3GHz CPU and the other 3.55GHz CPU. http://www.maximummidrange.com/46K7435.html also shows the cable but both connectors are different.

Comment: Ask the merchant

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Out of stock. No price yet. They will ask IBM. Here's a pic of the servers: https://scontent.fmex11-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/35710137_10156515899959708_5851810361463799808_o.jpg?_nc_cat=107&_nc_ht=scontent.fmex11-2.fna&oh=8cae817fa3e3f5f8e26ccc8d4afcada0&oe=5CC93E5E

Comment: What voltages,resistance on each pin?  you can see 100 Ohms?? and a cap.or polyfuse?  and series R?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Have updated original question with readings, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going with the conventional numbering

```
┌── ──┐
│5 3 1│
│6 4 2│
└─────┘
```

From the measurements. 1 and 4 appear to be ground, 2 is 5V/VUSB, and 3 is the chassis. That also matches the components, and the track widths - the DRC has made the power and ground lines thicker than the chassis ground (Which the DRC probably doesn't know is a power net). The component south of pin 2 is a suppression choke, and a little capacitor between chassis ground and ground to help EMI, but double check your measurements before you hook it up.

That just leaves the thin signal tracks on pins 5 and 6 for D+ and D-. Fortunately nothing terrible happens if you have these swapped - just things don't work. Given sod's law you'll probably get this wrong first time round...

The only USB cable for that motherboard, that I can find pictures of on the web, is an IBM 46K4646.  That has an 8 pin header - but with the pinout

```
1 brown
2 red
3 shield
4 black
5 green
6 white
7 nc
8 nc
```

That looks like a plausible match for your connector, so as a first guess
I'd go with green (D+) to pin 5 and white (D-) to pin 6.

so long as you don't short 5V to ground you should be fine. The USB spec. says that host controllers have to be tolerant of D+ and D- being shorted to +5V (originally for ever, but now for minutes) and ground.

Comment: Thanks James. Very thorough explanation! I noticed the same OP_USB 8 pin connector upper left that leads to the front USB for which I thought would be the exact same pinout for this connector, but with 6 instead of 8 pins. The connector key is also 180 degrees on the motherboard, and, save for the 2 extra non-use pins, basically should be the same. I also noticed my readings were off (miscalibrated) by about 1.2Ohms, which basically renders pins 1 and 4 at 0Ohms (and pin 3 at about 1.8Ohms), matching exactly what you said.

Comment: This connector here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/417763/help-identifying-6-position-2x3-computer-connector