# Help identifying 6 position (2x3) computer connector

Tags: connector, identification, header, pin-headers

Need help identifying this connector. I am actually looking to purchase a 6 (2x3) position connector of the same kind, so need help with type and where to buy (Mouser, etc).

This is from an IBM server (USB front connector). I want to build one such cable, but with 6 positions.

[image: connector photo 1]

[image: connector photo 2]

[image: connector photo 3]

[image: connector photo 4]

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Good luck http://www.ibselectronics.com/mechanical/connectors/  otherwise use a 2 x 3 std header socket and add an orientation key and lock.

Comment: take pictures without anything behind the plug ... your camera is focusing on your fingers and on the electronic components in the background .............. is there anything printed on the connector or on the plug that the connector plugs into?

Comment: I am guessing 2.54mm x 2.54mm  "
Product > Housing,Wafer and Terminal >  PV slim type **board to wire**,  keyed, with locking ears

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Do you have a link to the "keyed, with locking ears"?

Comment: not a chance, good luck , do you have any dimensions

Comment: I'll get them tomorrow... Seems like Molex Milli-Grid (without ears), I'll have to check (measure) pitch

Comment: The only place I've seen a connector like that is inside a Xerox Colorqube [sic] printer. Those are also made by foxon, so I suspect it's a foxon special... I had a quick look on alibaba but didn't find anything.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 - in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/417398 you can see the male side and a sata (0.050") connector. From that it looks to be 2mm pitch.

Comment: @james I see a 30 pin header not a 50 pin scsi although I measured the average pitch on the photo against the 6 pin header to be identical 27.3 pixels, so I assumed 0.1" or 2.54mm pitch

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 - I think we're talking crossed purposes there's a 7 pin SATA connector in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz99u.png labelled PAPESAS_SIGNAL. The distance between the 7 pins is 83 pixels and 0.3" or 7.62mm. The connector that mates with the one the OP asks about is J3_TAPEUSB_SIGNAL, the pitch is 22 pixels. (22/83)*7.62 = 2.019 mm - so I think it's 2mm

Comment: You are right, it's about  22 pixels (my err.) on J3 TABEUSB_SIGNAL but so is the 0.1" pitch 2x15 connector 10 pitches = 220 pixels

Comment: Haven't had a chance to power down the server and measure, but I was thinking it to be this: http://www.literature.molex.com/SQLImages/kelmscott/Molex/PDF_Images/987650-7941.PDF - Page 4, 78045-XX60 (specifically 78045-0660) - XX denotes: 04, 06, 08, 10, 12 Circuit Sizes - With side locks. That being a 2.00mm pitch 2x3 connector with what seems like side lock ears? No photo anywhere on the net, though.

Comment: Potentially - the ears look to be very diminutive little "ramps" on the side https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/780450660_sd.pdf